# iText image.setRotationDegrees() not keeping a consistent origin

Tags: java, itext

I am using iText for Java (5.5.13) and I am experimenting with rotating PDFTemplates using the Image class. The problem is that I can't understand what iText is using for the origin when rotating the images (and I apologise in advance if I am being stupid).

Attached is the code I am using

- I create a PDFTemplate
- Fill it with some arbitrary colour
- Create an image from this template
- Rotate image 90 degrees
- Set absolute coords for the image
- Add to the writer

Repeat again with a second rectangle but this time rotated only 30 degrees.

Shouldn't there be a common origin between the two shapes??
(It looks like there is an unwanted translation too)

```
// step 1
Rectangle pageSize = PageSize.A4;
Document document = new Document(pageSize);

// step 2
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(OUTPUT_FILENAME));

// step 3
document.open();

// step 4
float boxWidth = 200;
float boxHeight = 50;
float xStart = pageSize.getWidth()/2;
float yStart = pageSize.getHeight()/2;

// Add one filled rectangle rotated 90 degrees
{
    PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
    PdfTemplate textTemplate = canvas.createTemplate(boxWidth, boxHeight);
    textTemplate.saveState();
    textTemplate.setColorFill(BaseColor.RED);
    textTemplate.rectangle(0, 0, boxWidth, boxWidth);
    textTemplate.fill();
    textTemplate.restoreState();

    Image img = Image.getInstance(textTemplate);
    img.setInterpolation(true);
    img.scaleAbsolute(boxWidth, boxHeight);
    img.setAbsolutePosition(xStart, yStart);
    img.setRotationDegrees(90);
    writer.getDirectContent().addImage(img);
}

// And another rotated 30 degrees
{
    PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
    PdfTemplate textTemplate = canvas.createTemplate(boxWidth, boxHeight);
    textTemplate.saveState();
    textTemplate.setColorFill(BaseColor.BLACK);
    textTemplate.rectangle(0, 0, boxWidth, boxWidth);
    textTemplate.fill();
    textTemplate.restoreState();

    Image img = Image.getInstance(textTemplate);
    img.setInterpolation(true);
    img.scaleAbsolute(boxWidth, boxHeight);
    img.setAbsolutePosition(xStart, yStart);
    img.setRotationDegrees(30);
    writer.getDirectContent().addImage(img);
}

// step 5
document.close();
```

[image: I tried to attach what I see as an inline screenshot but don't have the reputation yet. You can see it here:]

Just to add background, I am doing this as I'd like to be able to wrap up text and images inside a rotatable and positionable contained (the image class which has fixed dimensions) which I can then use for building up a model of what is laid out where within the page (with a view to trying a word-art algorithm rather like wordle's).

Thanks!

Comment: To me it looks like iText is positioning the the bounding box of the rotated template at the given absolute coordinates, i.e. the rotated template is positioned so that its minimum *x* coordinate is `xStart` and its minimum *y* coordinate is `yStart`.

Comment: As an aside, your `textTemplate.rectangle(0, 0, boxWidth, boxWidth)` should have been `textTemplate.rectangle(0, 0, boxWidth, boxHeight)`, i.e. not `boxWidth` for both dimensions.

Comment: Yes sorry - typo from when I was tidying up the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Shouldn't there be a common origin between the two shapes?? (It looks like there is an unwanted translation too)

Your implicit assumption here seems to be that the template is first positioned and then rotated around some obvious special point, e.g. the lower left corner of the template.

This is not the case. Instead you can imagine that the template is rotated, then the bounding box (with edges parallel to the page edges) is determined, and the lower left corner of this bounding box is positioned at the coordinates you set using `Image.setAbsolutePosition`.

This becomes more obvious by drawing more rectangles, e.g. for 0°, 15°, 30°, 45°, 60°, 75°, and 90°:

[image]

Comment: This is really very helpful mkl - thank you. As a newbie I'm not sure how to accept this answer but it works for me.

Comment: *"As a newbie I'm not sure how to accept this answer"* - At the top left of the *answer*, there is from top to bottom an "up" arrow (for upvoting), a number (of votes), a "down" arrow (for downvoting), and a tick (for accepting). You as the person who asked should be able to trigger that tick. Also see the top of the [tour] page.